# Using conditional operator to indicate if value exists

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

I have variable named objectId.The objectId contains some string number.

In this row I try to check wether some value exists in objectId:

```
   self.showObjects = self.objectId == true ? true : false;
```

But even if value exists the `showObjects`  get false.

Any idea how to fix the row to make ot work properly?

Comment: what values can `self.objectId` have? is zero possible? or an empty string?

Comment: You want a simple `!! self.objectId` or `Boolean(self.objectId)`. No need to use a conditional operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
self.showObjects = !!self.objectId;
```

The use of `double not` will coerce the value to a boolean, which will always get converted to `truthy` or `falsy` values.

```
!!0 
!!""
!!false
!!NaN
```

All operations return `false`.

Any other non empty value will give you `true`.

Comment: You can simply link to http://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1048572. No need to explain everything again here :-)